# Why am I having issues with Ajax requests in dialogs?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a very simple html page which is rendered as a dialog. It is rendered the following way:

```
<a href = "simple.html" data-rel = "dialog" >
```

Simple.html page has following javascript code within < head > tags

```
<script>
   alert "hello";
</script>
```

Alert box is never  popped when simple.html is rendered as a dialog. However, when simple.html is rendered, not as a dialog, javascript gets executed.

What is the way to execute/include javascript code in a html page that is going to be rendered as a dialog.

EDIT: Javascript gets executed as long as it is within `< div data-role="page" > ........ < /div >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include your custom JS after you include jquery, but before you include jquery mobile.

Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: Actually this worked. Can you explain why it works this way, or could you point to resources which explain the reason

Comment: Added the link. That's the best exaplaination I could find

Answer (score 0):

In simple.html you must have to write **data-role="dialog"** instead of **"page"**